# How do I pass a whole URL with http e.g. "http://www.facebook.com" as a parameter to node/express "/:param"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I can't seem to pass a whole url e.g. "http://example.heroku.com/http://www.facebook.com"

```
app.get('/:url', function(req, res){
  var url = req.params.url;
  // do something with url...
}
```

I always get an error that says "Cannot GET /http://www.facebook.com".
How do I get past this?

Comment: http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com

Comment: You should use *encodeURIComponent* and *decodeURIComponent* http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp which turns the URL into http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com as @OrangeDog suggested

Answer (score 3):

Some characters (like `/`) have special meaning in URLs and need to be encoded.

```
http://example.heroku.com/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com
```

Most programming languages have a function (possibly via a third party library) which can encode that for you. In JavaScript, for instance, that is `encodeURIComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression. For example:

```
// http://localhost:3000/mountpoint/http://www.facebook.com
app.get( /^\/mountpoint\/(.*)/, function(req, res) {
  var url = req.params[0];
  res.json(url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments, answers but I've found out I could use the wildcard and I was able to get the whole URL parameter without running into the 'Cannot GET /' error

```
'/*'
```